# How to switch Lubuntu's desktop environment

Tags: lubuntu

I switched from LXQt to KDE recently unfortunately due to subsequent problems I had to face every day. There was only one mention of lxqt-config-monitor flooding system process in reddit, inevitably leading to losing access launching any applications, and worst of all, I couldn't gain access to the desktop via RustDesk.

I figured if I update lxqt to latest version (1.3.0) it'll fix everything, but it made it even worse somehow. So I switched to KDE, and surprisingly it's really a painless makeover. Now there's no lxqt-config-monitor flooding the system every 30 mins or RustDesk won't open. Everything just works the way I want it and I'd like to keep it that way

My understanding is if there's a Lubuntu update, will I be getting lxqt with it, no? I switched just by doing apt install kde-full, I'm afraid there's something more needed to be done to shave off lxqts remnants

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.